# Problem with loop In Python, loop is not defined

Tags: python

How to fix this? I cant find where is the mistake

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tiktodv2.py", line 124, in 
loop1()
NameError: name 'loop1' is not defined

So anyone can help me? I'm new

EDIT> Loop 1 and 3 doesnt work, because loop1 and loop3 arent defined.Must I remove all the quotes? I try and yes work with the first loop but idk if with the others too

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pyfiglet
from os import system
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1024, 650)

    """
    def loop1():
        time.sleep(60)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/button").click()
        except:
            print("You didn't solve the captcha yet")
            loop1()
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input").send_keys(username)
        except:
            print("Delay")
            driver.refresh()
            loop1()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/button").click()
        except:
            print("Either failed to input or can't find the button. Need to retry")
            driver.refresh()
            loop1()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Fans success delivered!")
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(250)
        loop1()
    """
        
    def loop2():
        time.sleep(60)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/button").click()
        except:
            print("You didn't solve the captcha yet")
            loop2()
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input").send_keys(vidUrl)
        except:
            print("Delay")
            driver.refresh()
            loop2()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/h5/button[2]").click()
        except:
            print("Either failed to input or can't find the button. Need to retry")
            driver.refresh()
            loop2()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Views success delivered!")
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(250)
        loop2()
    
    """
    def loop3():
        time.sleep(60)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/button").click()
        except:
            print("You didn't solve the captcha yet")
            loop3()
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input").send_keys(vidUrl)
        except:
            print("Delay")
            driver.refresh()
            loop3()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/h5/button[1]").click()
        except:
            print("Either failed to input or can't find the button. Need to retry")
            driver.refresh()
            loop3()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Hearts success delivered!")
        driver.refresh()
        time.sleep(250)
        loop3()
  

      """
    auto = 1
    
    if auto == 1:
        driver.get("https://homedecoratione.com/")
        loop1()
    elif auto == 2:
        driver.get("https://homedecoratione.com/")
        loop2()
    else:
        driver.get("https://homedecoratione.com/")
        loop3()
```

Comment: Yes, i do a edit for share the code, do you know what i must change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the triple quotes because they are commenting out your code:

```
def loop1():
    time.sleep(60)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/button").click()
    except:
        print("You didn't solve the captcha yet")
        loop1()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/form/div/input").send_keys(username)
    except:
        print("Delay")
        driver.refresh()
        loop1()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div[2]/div/button").click()
    except:
        print("Either failed to input or can't find the button. Need to retry")
        driver.refresh()
        loop1()
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Fans success delivered!")
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(250)
    loop1()

auto = 1

if auto == 1:
    driver.get("https://homedecoratione.com/")
    loop1()
```

Comment: can you see the edit? I must change the quotes in all the loops?

Comment: Yes, the quotes comment out your code which prevent the functions from being executed.